# Is there a Javascript API comparisson tool?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to update jQuery from version 1.4.2 to a newer one, and would like to see which methods were deprecated and removed between two arbitrary versions.

jQuery's API documentation is good, but change logs and release notes are scattered over a bunch of blog posts, in contrast to jQueryUI, which has a nice change log page.

Is there a tool to help with type of library migration/update?

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/ which lists removed APIs by the version they were removed.

Comment: That is a very good resource, it does solve my problem.